# How to read a csv file with commas in field with pandas python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

Hi I have a csv file  with items like this

```
product_id,url
100,https://url/p/Cimory-Yogurt-Squeeze-Original-120-g-745133
"1000,""https://url/p/OREO-Biskuit-Dark-&-White-Chocolate-123,5-g-559227"""
1002,https:/url/p/GARNIER-Micellar-Cleansing-Water-Sensitive-Skin-Pink-125-ml-371378
```

I tried using

```
import pandas as pd
productUrl = pd.read_csv('productUrl.csv',sep=","quotechar='"')
```

It returns back as

| product_id | url |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | https://url/p/Cimory-Yogurt-Squeeze-Original-120-g-745133 |
| 1000,"https://url/p/OREO-Biskuit-Dark-&-White-Chocolate-123,5-g-559227" |  |
| 1002 | https:/url/p/GARNIER-Micellar-Cleansing-Water-Sensitive-Skin-Pink-125-ml-371378 |

How do I read the csv? Because the url has commas in there too.

Comment: Can you create the file and separate the columns using a |? If so you could change your pd.read_csv to be pd.read_csv('productUrl.csv',sep="|"). I'm not sure how the file is generated, but if you have control of its creation then I would use the | technique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `quotechar='"'`, simply read it as is:

```
pd.read_csv('productUrl.csv')
```

*Be aware that your `pandas.read_csv()` example wont work cause it is missing a , between parameters*

###### Example

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csvString = """product_id,url
100,https://url/p/Cimory-Yogurt-Squeeze-Original-120-g-745133
1000,"https://url/p/OREO-Biskuit-Dark-&-White-Chocolate-123,5-g-559227"
1002,https:/url/p/GARNIER-Micellar-Cleansing-Water-Sensitive-Skin-Pink-125-ml-371378"""

pd.read_csv(StringIO(csvString))
```

###### Output

|  | product_id | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | https://url/p/Cimory-Yogurt-Squeeze-Original-120-g-745133 |
| 1 | 1000 | https://url/p/OREO-Biskuit-Dark-&-White-Chocolate-123,5-g-559227 |
| 2 | 1002 | https:/url/p/GARNIER-Micellar-Cleansing-Water-Sensitive-Skin-Pink-125-ml-371378 |

Comment: I did try doing sep too but it doesn't work. When I read the csv in text it returns like that. or should I use line break for sep?

Comment: `sep=','` is the default so you can just leave it out.